# PythonValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tags: python, pandas

The 2 dataframes I am comparing are of different size (have the same index though) and I suppose that is why I am getting the error. Can you please suggest me a way to get around that. I am looking for those rows in df2 whose user_id match with those of df1. Thanks and appreciate your response.

```
 data = np.array([['user_id','comment','label'],
            [100,'RT @Dvillain_: #oomf should text me.',0],
            [100,'Buy viagra',1],
            [101,'#nowplaying M.C. Shan - Juice Crew Law on',0],
            [101,'Buy viagra two',1]])

 data2 = np.array([['user_id','comment','label'],
            [100,'First comment',0],
            [100,'Buy viagra',1],
            [102,'Buy viagra two',1]])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,0:],columns = data[0,0:])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2[1:,0:],columns = data[0,0:])

df = df2[df2['user_id'] == df1['user_id']]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `isin`

```
df = df2[df2['user_id'].isin(df1['user_id'])]
df
Out[814]: 
  user_id        comment label
0     100  First comment     0
1     100     Buy viagra     1
```

Comment: Just beat me to it!

Comment: @pault just a little bit quick .I am lucky:-)

Comment: @Chandan yw~ happy coding